# git not uploading all my directories

Tags: git, github

I am not that good with git. I've just committed an existing directory to github (did `git add .`). but on github Web I see some of my directories and subdirectories are not listed there. If I run `git commit -am "message"` on my local machine I get

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I am afraid !! What to Do

-- EDIT -- (retelling the story)

The Directory was not empty. Initially There was 100s of files, Directories in another Directories. First I did git add . and then git commit -am "message" and then I pushed with git push origin master and now I see on github.com not all my directories ar listed. So I ran git commit -am "message" on my local machine. and then I got the output mentioned in my Question

Comment: Are the directories empty? Git doesn't track empty directories.

Comment: Thx. I was so confused.

Answer (score 4):

git -am won't add directories or new files. You need to use `git add`

Comment: `git add .` isn't recursive. Use `git add -A` if you want to add everything that doesn't match an ignore rule.

Comment: Can you paste exactly what you typed into the prompt? What happens if you use `git add --all`? When using the shorthand for `--all`, use only one dash like `-A`.

Comment: `git add -i` would be a useful thing to know to. It allows you to interactively add files. So Try `git add -i`, then use the add option to numerically pick the files you want to add. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `git add` your directories.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation.

Firstly, a commit is local operation that doesn't affect the remote repository. If you commit, nothing will show up on github. A `push` is what sends your commits to the remote repository.

Secondly, you cannot add empty directories to your project. The `add` command works for files and it will automatically add the directories which the file is in (if they're not already there).

Comment: The Directory was not empty. Initially There was 100s of files, Directories in another Directories. First I did `git add .` and then `git commit -am "message"` and then I pushed with `git push origin master` and now I see on github.com not all my directories ar listed. So I ran `git commit -am "message"` on my local machine. and then I got the output mentioned in my Question.

Comment: Try doing `git status` to find out what the status of the files are.